# Не удаляются элементы, не содержащие сыновей(листы). Как исправить

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Node // узел
{
    int info;
    Node *father, *lson, *rson;
};

typedef Node *Node1;

class Tree
{
private:
    Node1 Head;

public:
    Tree() : Head(NULL) {}//конструктор по умолчанию

    Tree(Tree &tr)
    {
        Head = NULL;
        tr.Clone(*this);
    }

    void Insert(int n) // Добавляем элемент в дерево
    {
        Node1 x = Head;
        Node1 a = NULL;
        Node1 b = new Node;

        b->info = n;

        while (x != NULL)
        {
            a = x;
            if (b->info < x->info)
            {
                x = x->lson;
            }
            else {
                if (b->info > x->info)
                    x = x->rson;
                else
                    return;
            }
        }
        b->father = a;
         if (a == NULL)
            Head = b;
        else
        {
            if (b->info < a->info)
            {
                a->lson = b;
            }
            else {
                if (b->info > a->info)
                    a->rson = b;
                else
                    return;
            }
        }
        b->lson = NULL;
        b->rson = NULL;
    }


    Tree(int n) // конструктор 
    {
        Insert(n);
    }

    Node1 Find(int n, int &c) //метод для поиска элемента
    {
        Node1 h = Head;
        c = 0;
        while ((h != NULL) && (h->info != n))
        {
            if (n < h->info) {
                h = h->lson;
                c++;
            }
            else
            {
                h = h->rson;
                c++;
            }
        }
        return h;
    }

    Node1 GetHead() {
        return Head;
    }

    void VivodSimv(Node1 x, ostream &out) //Выводим эл-ты
    {

        if (x == NULL)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            VivodSimv(x->lson, out);
            out << x->info << endl;
            VivodSimv(x->rson, out);
        }
    }

    bool DeleteNode(int n) //удаление узла
    {

        Node1 p = Head;
        Node1 f = NULL;

        while ((p != NULL) && (p->info != n))
        {
            f = NULL;
            if (n < p->info)//ищем эл кот удал
                p = p->lson;
            else
                p = p->rson;

        }

        if (p != NULL)
        {
            Node1 r = NULL;
            if ((p->lson == NULL) && (p->rson == NULL))//если лев и пр равны нулю то удал этот элемент
            {
                delete r;
                return true;
            }
            if ((p->lson == NULL) || (p->rson == NULL))//если хотя бы один равен нулю то удал и переставляем
            {
                Node1 son = NULL;
                r = p;

                if (p->lson != NULL)
                    son = p->lson;
                else
                {
                    if (p->rson != NULL)
                        son = p->rson;
                }

                if (f == NULL)
                    Head = son;
                else
                {
                    if (f->lson == p)
                        f->lson = son;
                    else
                        p->rson = son;
                }
            }
            else // случай с двумя сыновьями
            {
                Node1 left = p->rson;
                Node1 leftf = p;

                while (left->lson != NULL)
                {
                    leftf = left;
                    left = left->lson;
                }

                p->info = left->info;
                r = left;

                if (leftf->lson == left)
                    leftf->lson = NULL;
                else
                    leftf->rson = left->rson;
            }
            delete r;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    void DeleteTree(Node1 x) // удаление дерева 
    {
        if (x == NULL)
            return;
        DeleteTree(x->lson);
        DeleteTree(x->rson);
        DeleteNode(x->info);
    }

    void ObhodEnd(Node **x, void Fun(int)) //коцевой обход
    {
        if (*x != NULL)
        {
            ObhodEnd(&((**x).lson), Fun);
            ObhodEnd(&((**x).rson), Fun);
            Fun((**x).info);
        }
    }

    void Obchod(void Fun(int)) //ОБХОД
    {
        Node **x = &Head;
        ObhodEnd(&((**x).lson), Fun);
        ObhodEnd(&((**x).rson), Fun);
        Fun((**x).info);
    }

    ~Tree() 
    {
        DeleteTree(Head);
        cout << "Дерево успешно удалено" << endl;
    }

    void ObhodGlub(Node **x, Tree &t)//обход в глубину (по уровням)
    {
        if (*x != NULL)
        {
            t.Insert((**x).info);
            ObhodGlub(&((**x).lson), t);
            ObhodGlub(&((**x).rson), t);
        }
    }
    void Clone(Tree &x)
    {
        ObhodGlub(&Head, x);
    }

    const Tree& operator = (Tree &t)//присваивание
    {
        if (this != &t)
        {
            DeleteTree(this->GetHead());
            t.Clone(*this);
            return *this;
        }
        else
            return *this;
    }

};

void Print(int x)
{
    cout << x << "   ";
}

int main()
{
    Tree T; //создаем экземпляр класса Tree
    char a;
    int c = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    while (in >> a)
    {
        if (a == 'I')
        {
            int n;
            in >> n;
            if (T.Find(n, c) != NULL)
            {
                out << n << " : not inserd" << endl;
            }
            else
                T.Insert(n), out << n << " : inserd" << endl;
        }

        if (a == 'D')
        {
            int n;
            in >> n;
            if (T.Find(n, c) != NULL)
            {
                T.DeleteNode(n);
                out << n << " : deleted" << endl;

            }
            else
                out << n << " : not deleted" << endl;
        }

        if (a == 'F')
        {
            int n;
            in >> n;
            if (T.Find(n, c) != NULL)
            {
                out << n << " : found after " << c << " comparisons" << endl;
            }
            else
                out << n << " : not find after " << c << " comparisons" << endl;
        }

        if (a == 'L')
        {
            if (T.GetHead() == NULL)
                out << "Empty";
            else {
                T.VivodSimv(T.GetHead(), out);
                out << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    /*Tree T1;
    T1 = T;
    T1.SymV(T1.GetHead(), out);
    out << endl;
    Tree T2(T);
    T2.SymV(T2.GetHead(), out);
    out << endl;*/
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Трассируйте, рисуйте деревья, создайте тестовые цепочки. Создавайте програмные точки останова. За вас врядли это тут сделают.

Answer (score 1):

1. Конструктор `Tree(int n)` - нет инициализации поля `Head`.
2. Зачем в первом цикле `DeleteNode` постоянно делается `f = NULL;` - не ясно.

   Судя по стилю реализации, здесь должно было быть `f = p;`.
3. Что это за чушь в `DeleteNode`

   ```
   Node1 r = NULL;
   if ((p->lson == NULL) && (p->rson == NULL))//если лев и пр равны нулю то удал этот элемент
   {
     delete r;
     return true;
   }
   ```

   Но в этом месте `r` заведомо является нулевым указателем. Что вы "удаляете"?
4. Реализация `DeleteTree` - это вообще какой-то сюр. Зачем делать "поисковое" удаление узла, если узел *уже найден* и в каждом узле хранится указатель на предка?
5. С чего это вдруг функции `Obhod...` бросились использовать "двойные" указатели `Node **`?
6. Сокрытие указательных типов за typedef-именами - дикая практика. Неужели так трудно писать просто `Node *` вместо `Node1`?